# REGEX to search for and remove all characters up to and including the last hyphen

Tags: sql, regex

I am looking for a way to search for and remove everything up to and including the - from my strings below.  I have tried variations and none works exactly how I want it to. I tried `regex_replace`, but it did not catch all of them, and I found myself creating individual regexp statements for each scenario, which did not seem any better than hard-coding. I am hoping someone has a solution.  I would very much appreciate it.

```
POLY GON - HOME
POLY-GON-HOME
POLY - GON - HOME
POLY - GON HOME
PG - HOME
PG-HOME
```

I want to show everything after the second hyphen.  So, `HOME` is what I want to display.
I tried

```
regexp_replace(string,\A[^-]+-[^-]+)
```

but it removes everything except for the second hyphen.  Otherwise it works.

Comment: Show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: can you show what the desired results should be?

Comment: Do you want to remove up to the first or last `-`?

Comment: `^.*-` or `^.*?-` is the regexp, depending on whether you want the last or first `-`.

Comment: I updated my question to show what I want to display in my result, as well as what I tried.

Comment: I want to remove both the first and last -

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: `regexp_replace(string, '^.*-', '')`

Comment: Your call doesn't even look like proper syntax. The regexp needs to be in quotes, and you're missing the replacement string.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly @Barmar.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string, '^.*-', '')
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `.*` matches any string
- `-` matches hyphen

Since `*` is greedy, this will match everything up to the last hyphen. It then gets replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like:

```
select regexp_substr(string, '[^-]+$')
```

This basically keeps the last string of characters that are not hyphens.

Not all databases that support regular expression supports `regexp_substr()`, but they have some similar function.